# Joomla pass value from component to use in plugin and module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

How can I pass a value from component or set the certain value on a certain page that it then could be use in the plugin or module of joomla?

For example, in this view: `index.php?option=com_mycom&view=myview` will set `$a = 1` (it could be generated from database).

Every time people come to this address there will be a variable `$a = 1` that I could use it in my plugin.

I know some people suggest using session but it is not a good way for me to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an "answer" but you can use JRequest::set/get which would make content available in the global scope but not necessarily into a cookie, and the var would only be available per page request. http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Environment/JRequest.html

Comment: as udjamaflip said, pass value through url

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but there are no answers here, and things have moved on slightly from the original comment above. `JRequest` is now deprecated in recent versions of Joomla.

The current way to do this would be:

In your component code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->input->set('myvar', 123);
```

In your module/plugin code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->input->get('myvar');
```

As you say, using the session object is another way to do this, but it has the obvious downside of being persisted between web requests, which is often not what you want.