# How pass variable from template index.php to the component in Joomla?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, joomla3.0, joomla3.9

I use joomla 3.9.24.
In my template I have to pass a variable to the component (specifically com_content / article). In practice, depending on whether or not there are modules in a certain position, it must report the title in the article or not.
JRequest is deprecated as suggested in [Joomla pass value from component to use in plugin and module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393721/joomla-pass-value-from-component-to-use-in-plugin-and-module) I wrote this:

in the template index.php file

```
title_var = 1;
...
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$input->set('title_var', $title_var);
```

in the default.php file

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$title_var = $input->get('title_var');
```

But it does not work!
For example, if I insert

```
var_dump($input);
```

in both files, in the same page I will be shown the input data twice except for my title_var which in the var_dump of the component does not appear at all, as if the data did not pass.

How can i solve?

Update: the same using template parameters

in the template index.php file

```
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;
...
$variable  = $params->set('var_title', $var_title);
```

similar in the default.php file

```
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$paramsT = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;
...
$variable  = $paramsT->get('var_title'); #result null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to pas variables from templates to components..

Secondly You can use template parameters..

Comment: I also tried to use the template parameters, it was the first attempt being the most sensible one, but when I set its value dynamically in the component it isn't seen anyway.
I update the topic with the code I used for the template parameters.
Using sessions to pass variables seemed a bit too much in this case as it does not depend on the individual visitor's session but on a page setting.